# Angular 2 Http request does not send credentials

Tags: angular, http, typescript, credentials

I am working with Angular 2 and I am trying to send HTTP request with credentials:

This Angular 1 code works well, it includes the credentials:

```
$http.get("http://some.com/user",{ withCredentials: true})
```

According to the API preview I have implemented this Angular 2 code but it does not include credentials:

```
    http.get("http://some.com/user", {
        headers: myHeaders,
        credentials: RequestCredentialsOpts.Include
    }).toRx()
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(
        // onNext callback
            data => this.successHandler(data),
        // onError callback
            err  => this.failure(err)
    );
```

I am working with Angular 2.0.0-alpha.37.

Comment: RequestCredentialsOpts.Include has been removed, but for the moment, it's not any information about the right way in the future to set withCredentials -> https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4231

Comment: Answering my question. One of the principal Angular2 developers has fixed the issue, we'll be able to work with 'withCredentials' again. -> https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/5501

Answer (score 6):

I'm using `angular2@2.0.0-alpha.37`;

If you add code in `xhr_backed.js`, You can send 'credentials' to server

```
this._xhr.withCredentials = true;
```

#### angular2@2.0.0-alpha.37/src/http/backends/xhr_backed.js

```
var XHRConnection = (function() {
  function XHRConnection(req, browserXHR, baseResponseOptions) {
    ........
    this._xhr = browserXHR.build();
    this._xhr.withCredentials = true;
    ........
```

:)

Comment: It has been fixed by @robwormald -> https://github.com/robwormald/angular/commit/547ea806b881969ded22d4c2880d403f0393bbab

Comment: Really, this small answer should have a lot of up votes.

Comment: @dani however this pr is closed :(